# Why "negative" and "positive" limit solving the same equation different way?

Tags: calculus, limits

> $f(x)=1-x$ then, show that f(x) is continuous at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ but, f(x) is not differentiable at that point.

**Forget about continuous! I have confusion on differentiability.**

For Right Hand Derivative,

$$Rf'(\frac{1}{2})=\lim_{h->0_+} \frac{f(\frac{1}{2}+h)-f(\frac{1}{2})}{h}$$

$$=>\lim_{h->0_+} \frac{1-(\frac{1}{2}+h)-\frac{1}{2}}{h}$$
$$=> \lim_{h->0_+} \frac{-1}{1}=-1$$

For Left hand derivative,

$$Lf'(\frac{1}{2})=\lim_{h->0_+} \frac{f(\frac{1}{2}+h)-f(\frac{1}{2})}{h}$$

$$=>\lim_{h->0_+} \frac{(\frac{1}{2}+h)-\frac{1}{2}}{h}$$
$$=> \lim_{h->0_+} \frac{1}{1}=1$$

In second line of left hand derivative, we just "put" value of function in $f$. But, where did the $1$ go in second line of left hand derivative?

> [image]

The whole isn't in English that's why I didn't add definition.

> [image]

As you can see $f(x) = x$ when $x$ is greater than, or equal to zero and, less than $1/2$ ($0<=x<1/2$). And, $f(x) = 1-x$ when x is greater than or equal to 1/2 and less than 1 ($\frac{1}{2}<=x<1$). How can I know which condition is applied?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127171/discussion-on-question-by-istiak-why-negative-and-positive-limit-solving-the).

Comment: @Istiak Which book is that in Bengali ?

Comment: @cxi137 Yes! That is. Calculus |

Comment: @Istiak Calculus by whom ? writer ?

Comment: @cxi137 Prof. Dr. Fazlur Rahman Prof. Elias Hossain Prof. Hafizur Rahman Prof. Mydul Islam Book name : Advance calculus |

Comment: @md2perpe See [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190521/why-absolute-value-changes-function-in-limit)

Comment: @RobArthan /|\ See [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4190521/why-absolute-value-changes-function-in-limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is defined by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x, & \text{when } 0 \leq x < \frac12 \\
1-x, & \text{when } \frac12 \leq x < 1
\end{cases}
$$

The right hand derivative is defined as
$$
Rf'(x) = \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.
$$

Applying this to the given $f$ and at $x=\frac12,$ and then using $f(\frac12)=1-\frac12=\frac12$ and $f(\frac12+h)=1-(\frac12+h)=\frac12-h$ since the second part of the definition of $f$ applies for both $f(\frac12)$ and $f(\frac12+h),$ we get
$$
Rf'(\frac12) 
= \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{f(\frac12+h)-f(\frac12)}{h}
= \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{(\frac12-h)-\frac12}{h}
= \lim_{h\to0^+} \frac{-h}{h}
= \lim_{h\to0^+} -1
= -1.
$$

Similarily, the left hand derivative is defined as
$$
Lf'(x) = \lim_{h\to0^-} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.
$$

In this case we still have $f(\frac12)=1-\frac12=\frac12,$ but $f(\frac12+h)=\frac12+h$ since $\frac12+h<\frac12$ so the first part of the definition of $f$ applies. Thus we get
$$
Lf'(\frac12) 
= \lim_{h\to0^-} \frac{f(\frac12+h)-f(\frac12)}{h}
= \lim_{h\to0^-} \frac{(\frac12+h)-\frac12}{h}
= \lim_{h\to0^-} \frac{h}{h}
= \lim_{h\to0^-} 1
= 1.
$$