# Why absolute value changes function in limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

> If $f(x) = |x-1|$ then test the continuity and differentiability of the function $f(x)$ at the point $x=1$.

$$Rf'(1)=\lim_{h->0_+} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h->0_+} \frac{|1+h-1|-0}{h}$$
$$=1$$

$$Lf'(1)= \lim_{h->0_-} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h->0_-} \frac{-h-0}{h}$$
$$=-1$$

What is happening to second line? Both limit had used same function although why both of them are writing different "thing"? I am so confused with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For negative $h$, $1+h$ is ess than $1$ so $f(1+h)=|(1+h)-1|=|h|=-h$ by definition of absolute value (and sincee $h$ is negative).

Comment: But, absolute value always remain positive...

Comment: Exactely! Is $h$ positive or negative?

Comment: You wrote that |h|=-h .... For negative ones $h$ is negative... But, when it comes inside of absolute than that remains positive, doesn't it?

Comment: Write down values of $|h|$ when 1) $h$ is positive 2) $h$ is negative.

Comment: You did a typo mistake `kess` (less)...

Comment: @Istiak If $h<0$ then $-h$ is a **positive** number, just as the output of the absolute value of any number except zero should be.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute value in $f$ means that $f$ is defined differently for the two pieces of the domain:
$$f(x) = \vert x -1 \vert  = 
\begin{cases}
       x-1, &\quad\text{if }x-1\geq 0\\
       -(x-1), &\quad\text{if }x-1<0\\
\end{cases} \quad = \quad
\begin{cases}
       x-1, &\quad\text{if }x\geq 1\\
       1-x, &\quad\text{if }x<1\\
\end{cases}.$$

Then:

$$\lim_{h\to 1 ^-} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \dfrac{(1-(x+h))-(1-x)}{h} = \dfrac{-h}{h} = -1,$$

$$\lim_{h\to 1 ^+} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \dfrac{(x+h-1)-(x-1)}{h} = \dfrac{h}{h} = 1.$$

(Notice the limits have to be around the point $x=1$, not $x=0$).

It is the same function, but it is defined differently at the left ($x<1$) and the right ($x\geq 1$).

Since the limits do not coincide, $f$ is not differentiable at the point $x=1$.